# Different Versions of ionic/cli

Tags: macos, ionic6

I'm on MacOS Monterey if i run `ionic --version` outside of my users folder in /Users i get `6.20.1`. The same command inside of my users folder gives me `4.12.0`. Is this supposed to be like that?

Answer (score 1):

You have one `ionic` installed system-wide and one for the user. You can run `$ which ionic` inside and outside the user's home directory to see the location of both of the binaries.

Comment: with ```$ which ionic``` I get ```/usr/local/bin/ionic``` inside and outide of the folder. But maybe there is some non global installation

Comment: I ran npm uninstall without the -g flag inside the users folder and now it prompts the right installation. thank you